# Why Index object is not shared across different pandas objects that are reindexed with it?

Tags: python, pandas

As per *pandas* docs, `Index` objects can be shared between different series and dataframes.

So let's say I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), index=list("abcde"), columns=["x", "y"])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=list("abcde"))
```

It's also clearly stated that passing an `Index` object directly to `reindex()` is preferable to passing an array-like object, since it avoids duplicating data.

So I'm assuming that:

```
rs = s.reindex(df.index)
```

would use the same `Index` object for `s` as for `df`. However:

```
rs.index is df.index
```

is `False`, and I cannot understand why. Am I missing or misunderstanding something, or I'm reading an outdated section in docs?

Answer (score 0):

From [`pandas.Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), you are missing two things:

The very first thing is, you need to explicitly pass `copy=False` since this is `True` by default for `reindex`.

```py
rs = s.reindex(df.index, copy=False)
```

Second thing is, you are comparing the index of `rs` with the index of `df`, you should actually be comapring the index of `s` since you are calling `reindex` on the series `s`:

```py
>>> rs.index is df.index
False
>>> rs.index is s.index
True
```